# Page Break in Wkhtmltopdf

Tags: php, html, css, wkhtmltopdf, page-break

I'm using [WKHTMTOPDF](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) Tool to convert the web pages in to the PDF and it works great except some page break issues.

Like i have put the style

```
page-break-before: always;
```

for Table and it works great. while for avoiding the page breaks I have used :

```
page-break-inside: avoid
```

It works for some divs only.

Please check this snap for the issue.[image]

**Update:**

Here is the HTML code for the ROUND Shape which is not avoiding the page break.

```
<div style="float: left; position: absolute;
            top: -14px; right: -20px;
            border-radius: 50%; 
            border: 2px solid #fff; 
            background: #6a98f5; 
            font-size: 9px; 
            font-weight: bold; color: #fff;
            width: 34px; height: 34px;
            z-index: 99999; line-height: 30px;
            text-align: center;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;">
                                            78%
```

Comment: what happens if you pack it into another div? More complete HTML snippet would be useful.

Answer (score 4):

It might be a little too late to answer this, but it might help somebody with the same issue.

It seems that page-break is not happening when parent divs floats in some versions of htmltopdf. There's a little more info and a use case in:

https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/1604

Answer (score 0):

use this classes for page break :

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen,print">
       /* Page Breaks */

/***Always insert a page break before the element***/
       .pb_before {
           page-break-before: always !important;
       }

/***Always insert a page break after the element***/
       .pb_after {
           page-break-after: always !important;
       }

/***Avoid page break before the element (if possible)***/
       .pb_before_avoid {
           page-break-before: avoid !important;
       }

/***Avoid page break after the element (if possible)***/
       .pb_after_avoid {
           page-break-after: avoid !important;
       }

/* Avoid page break inside the element (if possible) */
       .pbi_avoid {
           page-break-inside: avoid !important;
       }

   </style>
```

How to write html code see example.

```
<div class="page1 pb_after">
   content 1...
</div>
<div class="page2 pb_before pb_after">
   content 2.... <table>...</table> 
</div>
```

Table rows break... It works :)

Comment: hi using  `page-break-after:always;`  in `tr`  does not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bookjs-eazy for layout and pagination control.

Used to ensure that pages are not truncated, while supporting bookmarks, directories, pages, and footers. Compatible with wkhtmltopdf

[enter link description here](https://github.com/wuxue107/bookjs-eazy/blob/master/README-en.md)